# Does `ndb.get_multi` add entities to memcache?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

We have a process where we need to `.get()` a large (~50-200) number of keys, multiple times, in one process. We can't use `ndb.get_multi` to get the keys all in one go, unfortunately. But we do know the keys in advance that we are likely to want. We are wondering -- would it be smart to `get_multi` these keys at the beginning of our process? Would that put the entities in memcache for faster lookup later?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They are added to memcache.

You can check it with app stats